# Bootstrap buttons not applying styles Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a situation here with my bootstrap buttons. I cannot get the styling to apply even though the css for the theme itself is working.

Here's my code

```
<%= button_to 'Sign Up', class: 'btn btn-green' %>
```

I tried another method, but this one gives me errors since the view isn't generated yet. But, I wanted to do was add html files that I already created for another website to the project. To use them as a view.

```
<%= button_to("View Web Page", {action: "Web_Page_To_Be_Used"}, class: "btn btn-primary") %>
```

Please, show me the best method.

UPDATE:

The code below has the best format for the link. The one I used was incomplete. For the placeholder text, you have to create a new route first. And then include it into the button's link.

= link_to 'Register', new_user_registration_path, class: 'btn btn-green btn-md' %>

Answer (score 0):

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to

html_options is the third argument of button_to so your second example is closer, you're probably getting an error because action expects a route.

```
<%= button_to("View Web Page", {action: "show"}, class: "btn btn-primary") %>
```